# Why `memmove` function has significant difference in two different computers?

Tags: c, performance, gcc

I've tried to run the following C code from two different computers.

```c
#include <string.h>

int a[100000];
int main(){
    for(int sz = 100000; sz > 1; sz --){
        memmove(a, a+1, 4*(sz - 1));
    }
}
```

Computer A uses 800ms, while computer B uses 6200ms. The running time of B is always far more than A.

### Environment

#### compile command

Shell is bash.
And the `-O` gcc command doesn't influence runtime.

```
gcc myfile.c -o mybin 
time ./mybin
```

#### Computer A

gcc 9.3.0

glibc: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9) 2.31`

`uname_result(system='Linux', release='5.4.0-100-generic', machine='x86_64')`

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6140 CPU @ 2.30GHz

#### Computer B

gcc 9.3.0

glibc: `ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) 2.31`

`uname_result(system='Linux', release='4.4.0-210-generic', machine='x86_64')`

CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8369B CPU @ 2.70GHz

### Question

Then I run the following file on same virtual machines, with different kernal version(4.4.210-0404210-generic x86_64 and 5.4.0-113-generic x86_64) with gcc 9.3.0. Two test cost less than 500ms.

```cpp
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define TICK(X) clock_t X = clock()
#define TOCK(X) printf("time %s: %g sec.\n", (#X), (double)(clock() - (X)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC)

int a[100000];
int main(){
    TICK(timer);
    for(int sz = 100000; sz > 100; sz --){
        memmove(a, a+1, 4*(sz - 1));
    }
    TOCK(timer);
}
```

How can I find the cause?

Comment: What do the gcc commands look like?

Comment: Do you run the same binary file on both machines?

Comment: @Hulk the binary file is slightly different, one file size is 16712B another is 16720B.
Other servers that run 300ms also have binary file size 16712B or 16720B.

Comment: Since gcc and glibc have the same version: (1) Different hardware (RAM) (2) Different firmware (chipset drivers) (3) Different hardware configuration (BIOS, UEFI RAM timings) (4) Glibc was built with a different configuration (e.g. MEMCPY_OK_FOR_FWD_MEMMOVE in [memcopy.h](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/generic/memcopy.h.html)). Differences in the glibc build may be detectable by linking statically with glibc (even though that's not really supported, apparently -- but should work on very similar systems like yours) and running *the same binary* on both.